# Xamarin Android app doesn't start with Xamarin Maps and customize pins

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I've been trying to implement customized pins for xamarin forms maps. After my initial tries in my own app I couldn't make it work, so I downloaded the last version of the sample code in [github](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/Map).

And updated the Nuget packages to the last version of forms (4.6.0) but the Android version doesn't work (says the app couldn't start) and the iOS app works fine.

The [tutorial also disappeared from the website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map-pin.md) so I don't know if there's some change going on there:

I've been trying to debug the issue in VS for MAC but seems to be I have a bug with the last version of VS:

```
06-04 15:16:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(14010): Process: com.companyname.customrenderer, PID: 14010
06-04 15:16:06.282: E/AndroidRuntime(14010): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.customrenderer-7-CQBJ6p0azbx9GlPttplw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.customrenderer-7-CQBJ6p0azbx9GlPttplw==/lib/x86, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.companyname.customrenderer-7-CQBJ6p0azbx9GlPttplw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/product/lib]]] couldn't find "libxamarin-debug-app-helper.so"
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO !

To use the Google Maps functionality in Android, you need to register for a Maps API key with Google. Until you do this, you will just see a blank grid instead of a map in your applications. You must obtain a Google Maps Android API v2 key - keys from the older Google Maps Android API key v1 will not work.

Obtaining a Maps API v2 key involves the following steps:

1. Retrieve the SHA-1 fingerprint of the keystore that is used to sign the application.
2. Create a project in the Google APIs console.
3. Obtaining the API key.

Have a look at this document : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key?tabs=windows